# "Error: Unary operator expected" when overloading operator '*'

Tags: c#, dll, struct, operator-overloading

I'm familiar with C++, currently trying to learn a bit of C#.
With that said, I have the fallowing 4 lines of code.

```
[DllImport(@"Graphics.dll")]
public static extern vec2 operator * (vec2 a);

[DllImport(@"Graphics.dll")]
public static extern vec2 operator / (vec2 a);

[DllImport(@"Graphics.dll")]
public static extern vec3 operator * (vec3 a);

[DllImport(@"Graphics.dll")]
public static extern vec3 operator / (vec3 a);
```

And in VCS Express, they give me the error `Overloadable unary operator expected` with the `*` and `/` underlined. Both are overloadable according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8edha89s%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). Though both operators are listed under binary, and not unary. What's going on?

And just for the sake of being compleate, here's the entire class, as is, for the DLL I'm wrapping:

```
class GraphicsDLL
{
    public struct vec2
    {
        float x, y;

        [DllImport(@"Graphics.dll")]
        vec2();

        [DllImport(@"Graphics.dll")]
        vec2(float ax, float ay);

        [DllImport(@"Graphics.dll")]
        public static extern vec2 operator + (vec2 a);

        [DllImport(@"Graphics.dll")]
        public static extern vec2 operator - (vec2 a);

        [DllImport(@"Graphics.dll")]
        public static extern vec2 operator * (vec2 a);

        [DllImport(@"Graphics.dll")]
        public static extern vec2 operator / (vec2 a);
    };

    public struct vec3
    {
        float x, y, z;

        [DllImport(@"Graphics.dll")]
        vec3();

        [DllImport(@"Graphics.dll")]
        vec3(float ax, float ay, float az);

        [DllImport(@"Graphics.dll")]
        public static extern vec3 operator + (vec3 a);

        [DllImport(@"Graphics.dll")]
        public static extern vec3 operator - (vec3 a);

        [DllImport(@"Graphics.dll")]
        public static extern vec3 operator * (vec3 a);

        [DllImport(@"Graphics.dll")]
        public static extern vec3 operator / (vec3 a);
    };
};
```

Comment: Sidenote: There is little reason to use `extern` for arithmetic operations of low dimensional vectors. The cost of interop is far greater than the cost of the dumb .net JITter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C# both `*` and `/` can only be overloaded as binary operators.  They can't be overloaded in unary form hence you're getting that error.  The `+` and `-` versions work because you are overloading the unary versions not the binary ones (addition, subtraction).

This error can be fixed by using the binary form of the operator

```
    [DllImport(@"Graphics.dll")]
    public static extern vec2 operator * (vec2 a, vec2 other);

    [DllImport(@"Graphics.dll")]
    public static extern vec2 operator / (vec2 a, vec2 other);
```

I suspect even this code won't work for you though at execution time.  It looks like you are attempting to PInvoke directly into a C++ member by the signature here.  If so that won't work.  You'll need to define a simple C entry point which calls into the C++ code and PInvoke into that function.

Comment: Of course `*` is a unary operator in C#, it's just not one that you can overload.

Comment: Great, thank's. It's all bunched as an `extern "C"` code block. But, we'll see.